# gmpy2 mpz type in a different base

Tags: python, gmpy

I am trying to use MPZ to change the base of a number, but when I try `mpz(16[, base=16])` I get an invalid syntax error.

If I use `mpz(0x16)`, it returns a base 10 number (`22`). Is it possible to store an MPZ type in a different base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `mpz` type always stores the value internally as binary. The optional `base` keyword is used for string conversion. Some examples:

```
>>> mpz("10", base=16)
mpz(16)
>>> mpz("10", base=32)
mpz(32)
```

To convert an `mpz` to a string in an arbitrary base, uses the `digits()` method.

```
>>> mpz("10", base=32).digits(16)
'20'
>>> mpz("10", base=32).digits(32)
'10'
>>> mpz("10", base=32).digits(2)
'100000'
```

Regarding the syntax error, the square brackets in the help text `[, base=0]` indicated that the keyword `base` is optional and the default value is `0`. The square brackets should not be entered.